# Random ordered sampling with replacement in SAS

Tags: sas, random

I have a data set from which I'd like to draw a sample with replacement. When I use `proc surveyselect`, the samples drawn are in the excact same order as in the original dataset and multiple draws are written below each other.

```
proc surveyselect data=sashelp.baseball outhits method=urs n=1000 out=mydata;
```

However, it's important to me that the position in the outtable is sampled as well. Is there an option in `proc surveyselect`, or am I better off to just sample the rownumber myself and output it, like outlined in [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/347-2012.pdf),p4?

As a toy example (not in SAS notation), suppose I have a list of values `[a, b, c, d]` and I draw five times with repetition (and keeping the order of draws):

First `a`, then `c`, then `a`, then `b`, then `c`. The result I want is `[a, c, a, b, c]`, but sas only gives output of the type

- `[a,a,b,c,c]` (with `outhits`)
- `[a 2, b 1, c 2, d 0]` (with `outall`) or
- `[a 2, b 1, c 2]` (without an additional option).

Answer (score 1):

So here is a solution which only requires BASE SAS. Minor changes would be needed to allow inclusion of additional columns such as an ID or a DATE, for instance. I don't claim it's the most efficient way to do this. It relies heavily on `PROC SQL` which is my preference. Having said that, it should produce the results you wish in quite reasonable time.

The length of the generated SQL code justifies the need for a separate sas program. If you don't want to show the whole `%included` file in the log, just leave out the `/source2` option.

### Generate Sample Data

```
data mymatrix;
  input c1 c2 c3 c4 c5;
  datalines;
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35
36 37 38 39 40
;
```

### Declare Macro %DrawSample

Parameters:

`lib` = library in which ds is found
  `ds` = table to sample from
  `out` = table to generate
  `outfile` = path/name of the sas program containing the insert strings
  `n` = number of repetitions

```
%macro DrawSample(lib, ds, out, outfile, n);

  %local nrows ncols cols;

  proc sql;
    /* get number of rows in source table */
    select count(*)
      into :nrows
      from &lib..&ds;

    /* get variable names */
    select name, count(name)
      into :cols separated by " ",
           :ncols
      from dictionary.columns
     where libname = upcase("&lib")
           and memname = upcase("&ds");

  quit;

  data _null_;
    file "&outfile";
    length query $ 256;
    array column(&ncols) $32;
    put "PROC SQL;";
    put " /* create an empty table with same structure */";
    put "  create table &out as";
    put "    select *";
    put "      from &lib..&ds";
    put "        where 1 = 2;";
    put " ";

    do i = 1 to &n;
      %* Randomize column order;
      do j = 1 to &ncols;
        column(j) = scan("&cols", 1 + floor((&ncols)*rand("uniform")));
      end;
      %* Build the query;
      query = cat("  INSERT INTO &out SELECT ", column(1));
      do j = 2 to &ncols;
        query = catx(", ", query, column(j));
      end;
      rownumber = 1 + floor(&nrows * rand("uniform"));
      query = catx(" ", query, "FROM &lib..&ds(firstobs=", rownumber,
                   "obs=", rownumber, ");");
      put query;
    end;
    put "QUIT;";
  run;

  %include "&outfile" / source2;

%mend;
```

### Calling the Macro

```
%DrawSample(lib=work, ds=mymatrix, out=matrixSample, outfile=myRandomSample.sas, n=1000);
```

Et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're after, but something that may help is to use the option `OUTALL` instead of `OUTHITS`.  This will create an output dataset the same size as the original, with a `selected` column to show if the record has been sampled and a `numberhits` column to show how many times that record has been selected.  It won't create a row for each time a record is selected.

You can then select the observation number for all records in the sample.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is even worse. I'm adding an example into the question.

Comment: Ok, I see what you want now, although I'm struggling to understand why the order of selection is important when it is random.  You could ask `proc surveyselect` to return just 1 record, then wrap a macro around it that loops through 1000 times, appending the result to an output dataset each time.  However, you wouldn't be able to replicate the result (using a `seed` would return the same record each time), so I wouldn't recommend

Comment: The order (or rather non-order) is important because I really want to shuffle around entries of a matrix for bootstrapping purposes.

Comment: You could use your existing code, add a column to the output dataset that contains a random number, then sort by that column.  This would create a random order which would mimic a random selection.  Adding a seed to the `proc surveyselect` and the random number generator (`ranuni` for example) means you will always return the same records and sort order, so the results can be replicated.

If you go down the macro route I suggested in my earlier comment then you won't be able replicate the results.